# PowerShell - Use a string in a foreach-object against the Description AD property of a computer object

Tags: powershell, variables, pipeline

I am trying to send a user name (SamAccountName) down the PowerShell Pipeline to find a computer based on the Description property in Active Directory:

The Description property is always "something-UserName"

I know I don't need to send the variable down the pipeline and can simply express it in the filter but I have s specific use case where I need to do this.

This is what I have tried:

```
"bloggsJ" | %{Get-ADComputer -server domain.com -Filter * -Properties Description | ?{$_.Description -eq "something-$_"}} | select Name
```

This produces nothing even though there is a computer with a description property of "Something-bloggsJ" on that domain.

Any advice please.

Comment: Still dont understand why Ivan's version is working but mine isnt.

Comment: That is because you are mixing the `$_` variable in your Where-Object (aka `?`) clause. In there, `$_` is the AD computer object as returned from `Get-ADComputer`, **not** also the user name you start the code with. That is why in my answer, I capture that name straight away in the ForEach-Object loop and can use that `$name` variable in  `-like "*-$name"`. I have added this explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Theo, I get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the underscore for `$_` variable:

```
"ivan" | ForEach-Object -Process { Get-ADComputer -Filter * -properties description | Where-Object -Property description -eq "something-$_"}
```

this one is working ...

Comment: Thanks Ivan, actuallym the underscore is there but doesnt appear in the published version of my question. I noticed that but the edit screen does show the underscore (strange.) However, that does work now that I have added -process before the script block. I didnt know about that, what does that do exactly? Anyway, thank you, it is working now!

Comment: It would be working without the parameter `-Process`, because it is positional, but it is a best practice to avoid aliases and use full parameter names. :)

Comment: @IanB If the answer is correct and you accept it as a solution, please mark it accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `-eq` operator, I would use `-like`.

Something like this:

```
"bloggsJ", "IanB" | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Description | 
    Where-Object {$_.Description -like "*-$name"}
} | Select-Object Name
```

<sup>Inside the ForEach-Object loop, the `$_` automatic variable is one of the usernames. Inside the Where-Object clause, this `$_` variable represents one ADComputer object, so in order to have the username to create the -like string, you need to capture that name before entering the Where-Object clause.</sup>

Comment: Now I see it, Thanks Theo!